# communication between c# application and minifilter driver

Tags: c#, driver, minifilter

is there any example of an c# application that's communicates with a minifilter via communication port?

thx

Comment: Did you ever find something for this?  I'm probably banging my head against the same things that you were.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use C# import a dll file.

I've tried to use c# directly to communicate with the driver, it is a mess.

The sample provide by WDK is excellent for studying.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to communicate c# application directly to port of minifilter driver then it will be a mess. Follow the steps and you will get it done.

- Connect cpp exe to port and get the data from minifilter (kernel mode) to user mode using that port.
- Use IPC mechanism to send or receive data from one end to another end.

  - create an exe in c# to get the data from the exe that connected to the port